# what the timestamp used for in Oauth

Tags: security, oauth

There is a timestamp in the Oauth authorization header. Anyone know what it is used for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is used (along with the nonce, which is randomly generated) to prevent replay attacks.

From http://hueniverse.com/2008/10/beginners-guide-to-oauth-part-iii-security-architecture/

> To make implementations easier, OAuth
>   adds a timestamp value to each request
>   which allows the Service Provider to
>   only keep nonce values for a limited
>   time. When a request comes in with a
>   timestamp that is older than the
>   retained time frame, it is rejected as
>   the Service Provider no longer has
>   nonces from that time period. It is
>   safe to assume that a request sent
>   after the allowed time limit is a
>   replay attack.